# SSE instruction invoked without sequence

Tags: assembly, sse, masm32

**Hello,**

i have just starts with Assembly, so im not a pro, this morning i have tried this code.

```
fItem real4 2321.3
    main proc
        cvtss2si eax, xmm0
        print str$(eax), 13, 0
        movss xmm0, fItem
        ret
    main endp
```

im using masm32 so i have the print MACRO,
the probleme is that the output of eax is 2321 even when i mov the fItem to xmm0 after the print, so im not sure of what happen.
thanks for your answers in advance :).

Comment: More than likely it's undefined behavior, since `xmm0` isn't initialized. The fact that it still prints 2321 is either by pure chance, or `xmm0` somehow winds up with the value in `fItem` before `main` is called.

Comment: Thats not chance coz i have change the value and still print it, it may be initialization, but i have been looking at VC11++ assembly output and i can't any initialization.

Comment: There might be other code somewhere else, either in a different object file (like the CRT that calls `main`), or it may be part of an init segment.